# Ajax - Erro 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, ajax, servidor

> GET
>   http://localhost/Ultraweb_20150629_adriano/Ultraweb/index.php/supervisaocontroller/estadoMaquinaMobAjax/37/37/100/500
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Minha função

```
function estadoDinamico(indice, key, width, height){


    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url : '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/supervisaocontroller/estadoMaquinaMobAjax/'+key+'/'+indice+'/'+width+'/'+height,
        success: function(data){

            $('#contentSupervisao'+indice).html(data);
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url : '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/supervisaocontroller/ConfigPersonalizadaAjax/'+key+'/'+indice,
                success: function(data){

                    $('#contentConfigPers'+indice).html(data);
                    setTimeout(
                            function(){
                                estadoDinamico(indice, key, width, height);
                            }, 2000
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

dai ocorre o erro, alguem poderia ajudar??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olhei no console do navegador (f12 - Chrome) na aba network, na página onde ocorreu o Internal Server Error e vi qual foi o erro exatamente.

Como a função vem de uma requisição ajax o erro não é mostrado no console ou no erro do PHP. É mostrado apenas o erro 500. Na aba mostra o erro da linguagem, que no meu caso php, e foi a falta de uma procedure para executar o método de criar o html para a tela.